# Tkinter not responding

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Python and to all programming at all so maybe it is obvious mistake.

My graphic windows is not responding. This program is supposed to draw 10 pictures at random locations. Then it should ask for `dx` and `dy` over and over again, without end, which are numbers that should move my first popped picture. Pictures are there and it is asking for these two parameters but it is not responding and also when I insert them, nothing happens. I think the code should be right, but I am not sure. Thanks for responding :)

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter
c = tkinter.Canvas(width = 400,height = 400)
c.pack()
x1 = random.randrange(100, 400)
y1 = random.randrange(100, 400)
pic1 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = 'images2-1.png')
c.create_image(x1, y1, image = pic1)
pic2 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = 'images2-1.png')
for i in range (0,9):
    x = random.randrange(100, 400)
    y = random.randrange(100, 400)
    c.create_image(x, y, image = pic2)
    c.update()    
while 1:
    dx = int(input('zadaj dx: '))
    dy = int(input('zadaj dy: '))
    c.move(pic1, x1+dx, y1+dy)
    c.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems. First, take a look at a [simple Hello World program](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program) in Tk to see how it should be structured. Basically, you're not calling Tk's main loop. However, the user input will always block the application main loop, so you need to move that work to another thread.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I will take a look at that program, thanks.
What do you mean under another thread? I am not native English speaking, so I am not sure.

Comment: @MichalOndrejicka Don't worry, me either. I'm talking about the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module, which lets you run multiple tasks *"simultaneously"* so the input won't block your application's main loop.

Comment: Use entry boxes to get the input so it can all be done in Tkinter (the command called gets the entries and moves the pictures), similar to the examples at http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_entry_widgets.php

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment to a previous answer: make it a ”pure” GUI application. It's conceptually simpler to add some labels, entry boxes and a button than keeping the user input in the text console and using threading to combine this with a GUI.

```
import tkinter as tk
from itertools import islice
from random import randrange


def iter_random_coordinates(lower, upper):
    while True:
        yield (randrange(lower, upper), randrange(lower, upper))


class MainFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.image = tk.PhotoImage(file='test.gif')
        random_coordinates = iter_random_coordinates(100, 400)
        self.x, self.y = next(random_coordinates)
        self.image_id = self.canvas.create_image(
            self.x, self.y, image=self.image
        )
        for x, y in islice(random_coordinates, 9):
            self.canvas.create_image(x, y, image=self.image)

        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        tk.Label(frame, text='zadaj dx:').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        self.dx_entry = tk.Entry(frame)
        self.dx_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.EW)
        tk.Label(frame, text='zadaj dy:').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        self.dy_entry = tk.Entry(frame)
        self.dy_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.EW)
        frame.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        tk.Button(self, text='Move', command=self.do_move).pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.dx_entry.focus_set()

    def do_move(self):
        dx = int(self.dx_entry.get())
        dy = int(self.dy_entry.get())
        self.canvas.coords(self.image_id, self.x + dx, self.y + dy)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = MainFrame(root)
    frame.pack()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```